# security related to directories

Tags: security, penetration-testing, application-security

How do you fix a directory traversal issue?
Disable directory listing in Apache or IIS configuration
Search replace ../ from the parameter
Add a blank index.html file in the webroot
Carry out input validation or use database tokens for files

Answer (score 0):

For Apache, I think placing the option `Options -Indexes` to the .htaccess file.
See http://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/prevent-directory-listing-htaccess.shtml and http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-web-server-prevent-directory-folder-listing/